# Use VBA macro to find substring in word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to find a string in word document and replace it, with it's sub string using vba code.

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if your provided more information, such as an example of what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Mid method for the sub string purpose

```
Sub WordReplace()
    Dim sSample, rResult As String
    sSample = "hello world is my program"

    ' Sub String (replacing word)
    rResult = Mid(sSample, 1, 5)

    Set rRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    rRange.Find.Execute FindText:=sSample, ReplaceWith:=rResult, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim TextToFind as String
    TextToFind = "test"

    Dim TextToReplace as String
    TextToReplace = "testing"

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = TextToFind
        .Replacement.Text = TextToReplace
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

This is directly pulled from Record Macro functionality within Word.